# Store and Manage Data for Simple App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, plist, nsdata

I will make a simple game app which will store some data as user progresses in levels. For example: each level has a number of sub-levels, sub-level stores 3-4 properties (strings and arrays) depending on user's progress.

The app is simple and it is not a lot to store (about 150 levels and sub-levels maximum with small amount of data in each) and I do not want to make it complicated with multiple classes representing levels and sub-levels plus SQLLite database. I thought of a simpler approach but good enough to manage data through my GameManager singleton.

Recommend what approaches to look at for my needs to store and manage data for this type of an app. Perhaps one of these or something else:

1. **NSUserDefaults** + **NSDictionary**
2. **CoreData** + **SQLLite**
3. etc...

Just want to make sure I am not missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much better and less painful for you to use core data. Why do you say sqlite?? Core Data is just saving your objects in a sqlite file on an iOs device and in xml in Cocoa app. 
To use plist files is kind of strange, as I think. You can put into it only a simple array, and what if you want to display photos besides your simple array? The preferred way is core data - 50% less code, as apple says. Use NSFetchedResultsController and you'll be good!

Answer (score 0):

Another widely used practice would be to store your information in a property list (.plist).  [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) come equipped with the capability to load from as well as write to a property list.

Here's a resource which may be helpful to you: [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into core data. It seems very difficult once you get started. But once you get into it, it gets pretty straightforward from there. Check out this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBrkavVJsw0) he helped me get going. Hth